# Google app engine maven archetype HelloWorld endpoint project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to build and run this project locally using Eclipse with google cloud plugin installed but the project is showing errors.

I have uploaded the project on Github. You can find it here.

[Github maven based google app engine endpoints project](https://github.com/Takshaksh/Tests/tree/master/hello)

Nothing is modified just a plain project form the maven repository.

Here is a screenshot of the error.
[image]

Comment: Did you try ignoring the `<goal>` tag in your pom.xml file? It seems like the solution in a lot of cases like this. Let me know if this was helpful. More information can be found [here](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html#ignore-plugin-goal)

Comment: I have already uploaded the whole project on Github, Please check it there. Link is given above

Comment: I checked your pom.xml file and i noticed these lines: `<goals>
                            <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                            <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                        </goals>` According to [this documentation](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/display-dependency-updates-mojo.html) this tag just displays all dependencies that have newer versions available. As this is not crucial for deploying your project in Eclipse I would suggest you to add the `<ignore>` tag in order to to silently ignore the plugin execution.

Comment: I don't know how to use <ignore> case but I tried after removing the goals and it shows this in the build:

[ERROR] Could not find goal 'devserver' in plugin com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1 among available goals deploy, deployCron, deployDispatch, deployDos, deployIndex, deployQueue, genRepoInfoFile, help, run, stage, start, stop -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Comment: In order to use the ignore tag you have to follow the [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html#ignore-plugin-goal) in my first comment. Please try that and let me know if it worked for you. Thank you.

Comment: The documentation pom file is not same as project pom file but if I add the ignore tag inside action tag then it shows this error on execution.......

[ERROR] Could not find goal 'devserver' in plugin com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1 among available goals deploy, deployCron, deployDispatch, deployDos, deployIndex, deployQueue, genRepoInfoFile, help, run, stage, start, stop -> [Help 1]
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoNotFoundException.
...... Can you try it out at your system and see yourself if possible - of course

Answer (score 0):

According to [MojoHaus documentation](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/index.html):

> "versions:display-dependency-updates scans a project's dependencies and
>   produces a report of those dependencies which have newer versions
>   available."

**AND**

> "versions:display-plugin-updates scans a project's plugins and
>   produces a report of those plugins which have newer versions
>   available, taking care of Maven version prerequisites."

In order to resolve this issues please try the following changes in your pom.xml file:

1. Update version to 2.2.1:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
       <artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
       <!-- Update version -->
       <version>2.0.7</version>                         
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Update version to v 1.0.2 and add your projectID :

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
       <artifactId>endpoints-framework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <!-- Update version -->
       <version>1.0.0</version>
       <configuration>
           <!-- add project id here -->
           <hostname>YOUR-PROJECT-ID.appspot.com</hostname>             
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```
3. Update the App Engine Maven plugin to the newest version.

*Please keep in mind that according to [Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/migrating#migrate_using_maven_or_gradle)*

> *The old App Engine Maven plugin, with group **com.google.appengine**, is incompatible with the Endpoints Frameworks plugin. You must use the new version.*

You shall find the latest version [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.tools/appengine-maven-plugin)

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- Update version here -->
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- deploy configuration -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```